# Shall I connect inverter with boat GND?

Tags: wiring, grounding

A friend of mine is building a boat. On this boat, he has 12V batteries with a 230V/13A transformer.

Recently somebody suggested he should connect the null with the ground. With DC, this is common practice. But how would somebody suggest doing the same with AC?! Polarity switches continuously on AC.

I suspect he either misunderstood the advice or the advisor didn't understand it himself either.

What might the advisor have wanted to tell? There's no reason to assume malicious intent.

Comment: Null? or Hull...?

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle Although the difference is subtle in English, it's not in my native language. Confusion between the two is just about impossible.

Comment: Ok. It's just that I'm not familiar with "null" in that context.

Comment: Possibly talking about connecting the neutral and the ground connections in an AC system?

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle An electric socket has three 'sides': Phase, null and ground.

Comment: Not in my language it doesn't - it has live, neutral and earth.  I suspect you want to link earth and ground?

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle Exactly :-)

Comment: In a three-phase star system the neutral would be at 0 potential and is connected to earth. Not sure you'd want to do that with a single phase inverter, since they often don't have neutral, but live and anti-live (or phase and phase>>180°)

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle Which is exactly why the advice sounds so preposterous to me and I suspect the advisor meant something else. There's no three-phase available on board, just single.

Comment: If "Phase" and "Null" mean the same as "Live" and "Neutral" in the UK then DO NOT connect Null to Ground. Connect the separate Ground on the socket to the boat's ground. Connecting Neutral to Ground should simply trip the breaker, but in older systems before RCDs, could be dangerous (if, for example, a wiring error transposed Live and Neutral)

Comment: @BrianDrummond They're most probably the same thing. The ground is currently connected to the boat's ground. I should've stated I'm aware of how a ground is supposed to work. I see this questions causes as much confusion here as it initially did to me.

Comment: He might have been on about connecting the AC Earth in the socket to the AC Neutral (Null / Cold) at the inverter's output in order to force a breaker trip from overcurrent (MCB) or live/neutral mismatch (RCD) if there is a short of live->earth.

Comment: The question implies that the hull of the boat is made of a conducting material, eg. metal, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Presumably the suggestion is to wire either the "neutral" wire or the "ground" wire from the inverter to boat "ground".  In most cases I would expect the inverter to have a separate "ground" wire coming out, and, if present, that should almost certainly be wired to boat "ground".  If a "ground" wire is not present then the "neutral" should *probably* be wired to boat "ground", but one would want to think about it a bit.  "Boat ground", for a non-metal hull, would be an exposed metal plate on the outside of the hull, below water line.

Comment: @Kitana The boat is mostly made out of polyester. However, there's an artificial ground consisting of a large amount of metal connected to the water. Which basically substitutes a metal hull.

Comment: "Metal connected to the water" ??? Perhaps to drain static charges? Anyway, the ground wire and the concept of grounding is about protecting people. The question is, when you touch one wire can current flow trough you. On a good isolating floor this isn't the case. Also an RCD (GFCI) would not trigger. However, when there are more devices, especially with metal cases, it can make sense to implement Majenkos proposal. Also with connection to the "large amount of metal", on a boat one doesn't know where the water reaches.

Comment: @Kitana In general, on a boat, the "large amount of metal" is the big lump underneath designed to keep the boat upright (the "keel"). If that's not in the water, then you're either on land, or the boat's upside down and a ground connection is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the "adviser" may have been talking about connecting the socket's earth to the inverter's neutral / cold / null point:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpxsZ8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this arrangement, if there is a short or other fault causing current to flow through the earth connection, it will either cause enough current to flow to trip / blow the MCB or Fuse, or cause a mismatch in the live / neutral currents which would trip an RCD (GFCI).  You could also add an ELCB into the mix as well, and that would function normally.

Comment: Wouldn't the GFCI be pulled anyway? The ground of the socket is wired to the ground of the meterbox (located between the transformer and the boat's sockets). Although I'm not familiar with the exact internal circuitry of said box, I always assume there's a current meter (probably some relay) inside pulling a switch when the current goes over 30mA.

Comment: I don't know. All this is supposition and guesswork. We don't know how the boat is wired, what the inverter provides, what fuses / trips there are in the circuit, if any.  This is how I would wire the earth pin of the socket up, but I would be reticent about connecting it to anything else that isn't part of that AC circuit due to how a typical inverter works. Details about the internal workings of the inverter would be useful too since there are different ways of generating the AC waveform.

Comment: This connection will trip the RCD/GFCI **in normal operation** by diverting >20ma from the neutral line to the ground connection.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Where to?

Comment: aaaah wait, the question is ambiguous; he asks about a 230/12 transformer (not a 12/230V inverter). I (and Peter B) have been interpreting that as a 230v *to* 12V transformer to charge from a shore power hookup when available : the fact that he mentions 13A which is a standard UK outlet supports that. **If** he actually means a 12V to 230V inverter then you are entirely correct, neutral and ground should be connected at source - i.e. at the inverter. And this supply must never be connected accidentally to shore power. Some clarification required, I think...

Comment: @BrianDrummond That's only one small bit of the ambiguity. The whole question is so fuzzy the only possible answers are all based 100% on guesswork and personal interpretation.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The transformer is 3kW, which at 230V is about 13A. It has 12V input, 230V output. And yea, it's a fuzzy question. Next time I'll just let him sort out his own trash. Thank you all for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

> But how would somebody suggest doing the same with AC?! Polarity
>   switches continuously on AC.

**This is not advise or complete answer for your main question, just explanation about GND.**

Voltage is difference between two terminals.

In the other words - there is no voltage in one terminal. Voltage must be between two terminals.

GND can be used as point of reference and sometimes as conductor in some cases (cars, boats) to reduce cost of wiring. It is also commonly used method. You can read more about grounding here: [Where is the ground/negative for overhead power lines?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107534/where-is-the-ground-negative-for-overhead-power-lines/)

If you connect one terminal to GND and say "this is zero" - other terminal relatively to this will have variable voltage - sometimes positive, sometimes negative.

[image]

---

If you have a boat and you will connect 12V battery `-` to `GND` and say "this is zero" - other terminal will have +12V relatively to GND.

---

If you connect battery `+` to `GND` - other terminal will have -12V relatively to your ground.

Answer (score 2):

The shore power neutral **must not** be connected to vessel ground.  When the inverter is operating, the on-board neutral must be connected to vessel ground.

The shore power "safety ground" should be connected to the vessel ground, preferably through a Galvanic Isolator.

The above rules are from ABYC (USA) and CSA (Canada), but, according to a British book I have, apply there as well.

Comment: Marine (and mobile/RV) inverters have built-in [bond switching](https://www.bluesea.com/resources/89) to bond neutral and ground when powered on, but break the bond when powered off so it doesn't bond the shorepower connection.